# suavizar el Scroll horizontal en js vanilla

Tags: javascript, html, css, eventos, scroll

Tengo un scroll horizontal en mi pagina web, en el body, y su scroll se nota muy torpe ¿Cómo hacer que la transición se sienta suave a la vista?. **Simplificando un ejemplo parecido seria como este:** "ejecuten"

**NOTA:** le puse -200, 200 para que se note mejor el efecto torpe que quiero suavizar.

```js
const element = document.querySelector("#container");
 
element.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
 
  element.scrollBy({
    left: event.deltaY < 0 ? -200 : 200, //es un operador condicionl(ternario)- condition ? val1 : val2
    
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  
  max-width: 50rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
 
#container p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #ff6961;
  color: white;
  
  padding: 2rem 3rem;
  margin: 2rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>9</p>
    <p>10</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución muy sencilla es usar CSS, hay una propiedad específica para lo que quieres:

```
scroll-behavior: smooth;
```

Aplicada a tu código de ejemplo:

```js
const element = document.querySelector("#container");
 
element.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
 
  element.scrollBy({
    left: event.deltaY < 0 ? -200 : 200, //es un operador condicionl(ternario)- condition ? val1 : val2
    
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  
  max-width: 50rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
 
#container p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #ff6961;
  color: white;
  
  padding: 2rem 3rem;
  margin: 2rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>9</p>
    <p>10</p>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias por el dato, me puse a revisar y encontré la forma JavaScript;

Answer (score 1):

**Para la forma JavaScript solo hacia falta agregar `behavior: 'smooth'`**

```js
const element = document.querySelector("#container");
 
element.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
 
  element.scrollBy({
    left: event.deltaY < 0 ? -200 : 200, //es un operador condicionl(ternario)- condition ? val1 : val2
    behavior: 'smooth'
    
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  
  max-width: 50rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
 
#container p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #ff6961;
  color: white;
  
  padding: 2rem 3rem;
  margin: 2rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>9</p>
    <p>10</p>
</div>
```